# How to change the .MuisvgIcon-root class styles to override new styles from library in material-ui react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-ui for UI components in my `create-react-app` project. As per my requirement i decided to use drawer and App-bar component together in dashboard application. But i have an issue with changing the color of SVG icon.

Here the screenshot, what i exactly wanted to change

[image: change icon color living in inside circle]

Here is my toolbar code :

```
 <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="open drawer"
              onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
              edge="start"
              className={clsx(classes.menuButton, {
                [classes.hide]: open,
              })}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
              VOTTUN BLOCKCHAIN
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
```

I want to change the color of icon to white.

How we can do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Different scenarios:

If you want to

1. Override MuiSvgIcon-root to change Color to blue:

```
    .MuiSvgIcon-root {
        color: blue !important;
    }
```

2. Override MuiSvgIcon-root to change Color to blue
   After Accordion expanded:

```
    .MuiAccordion-root > .Mui-expanded {
        .MuiSvgIcon-root {
            color: blue !important;
        }
    }
```

3. Override MuiSvgIcon-root to change Color to blue
   After Accordion expanded
   And accordion is in a parent has a class name as `my-parent-class`:

```
    .my-parent-class {
        .MuiAccordion-root > .Mui-expanded {
            .MuiSvgIcon-root {
                color: blue !important;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change by applying css properties.
example,

```
<div classname="drawer">
    <IconButton />

</div>

#css
.drawer > .MuiSvgIcon-root{
color:gray
}
```

(BEM naming )

Answer (score 0):

Apply color rule to classes.menuButton

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  menuButton: {
    color: 'red'
  },
}));
```

You can refer to this [Codesandbox working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-skmw1?fontsize=14)